# How to listen to Metamask Ethereum events

Tags: metamask, javascript

I am trying to listen to the `chainChanged` event for Metamask, but the event never fires. When running the following snippet, I get a `console.log` of the `chainId` once, but the `chainChanged` event never runs. What could be the issue? Thanks!

```js
if (window.ethereum) {
  window.ethereum.send('eth_chainId')
        .then(handleChainChanged)
        .catch((err: any) => console.error(err));
    
  window.ethereum.on('chainChanged', handleChainChanged);

  window.ethereum.autoRefreshOnNetworkChange = false;
  ...
}
    
function handleChainChanged(chainId: number) {
  console.log(chainId);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Current Answer

Your question now contains the valid answer. Use `chainChanged` event instead that specified in [`EIP-1193`](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1193#chainchanged) ([also in MetaMask](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html#events))

```js
window.ethereum.on('chainChanged', handleChainChanged);
```

The `networkChanged` event has been deprecated in [`EIP-1193`](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html#legacy-events) ([also in MetaMask](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html#legacy-events))

### Original Answer from 2020

<strike>Try `window.ethereum.on('networkChanged', handleChainChanged)`</strike>

From what I know, the new MetaMask api (which will change this command to `chainChanged`) is not yet live.